# Firebase - how to get all values under a certain key from multiple nodes?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner user of android studio.I need your help in this issue.
 I wrote a code to save strings in firebase database, and I want to write a code that retrieve all the values under a certain key from multiple nodes and display it in a listview.
How can I do so ?

`data structure:`

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share us some code.

Comment: Can you share your data structure?

Comment: @Renaud T. I shared my data structure

Answer (score 0):

```
DataBase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
            a.add(dataSnapshot.child("imageURL").getValue().toString());
            a.add(dataSnapshot.child("n1").getValue().toString());
            a.add(dataSnapshot.child("n2").getValue().toString());
            a.add(dataSnapshot.child("n3").getValue().toString());
         }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

              }
      });
```

and after that set this list to adapter using setAdapter .. 
I hope this code will help you :)